# benefit of generators in fibonacci series

Tags: python, generator

I just saw an example of Fibonacci series using a generator from a webpage.
This is the example I saw

```
def fibonacci(n):
    curr = 1
    prev = 0
    counter = 0
    while counter < n:
        yield curr
        prev, curr = curr, prev + curr
        counter += 1
```

The user can input the limit 'n'.

My question is what's the use of using generator here? 
 how generator benefits the user here? 
What advantage he gets instead of just using a normal print message here to print the series?

I am agreeing if the user has to store the value in a list and process it later, yield can do generate number on fly.

What could be the use of yield in this case?

Comment: You may not want to store the whole result of `fibonacci` (*might be a pretty big list and you can't afford that much memory*). Rather, you may want to store and process a value at a time. Additionally, generators come in handy if you are not planning to iterate over the whole sequence (*You can just provide a really high number, and keep generating numbers until you are satisfied*)

Comment: I agree that. But in the above example, what is the problem if i remove yield statement  with  a variable to store the generated value and process that value such that next iteration I overwrite that variable ?

Comment: @MatiasCicero I think this goes for a complete answer than a comment...just shove in an example! Unless there is a possible duplicate

Comment: @syam: how would the code *calling* the function get access to the intermediate results? If you are replacing the variable each iteration, the caller would not have access to it.

Comment: Using `yield`/a generator, you would not even have to provide an upper bound `n`. You could just have this generate an infinite stream of Fibonacci numbers.

Comment: @MartijnPieters What i meant is  say I want to get each fibanocci  number and I want to store it in a list. So in this case,   instead of yield statement, I can replace yield(curr) by  new_array.append(curr). OR also  I can retain the same yield(curr) but in the next() to get the value, i can use new_array.append(curr). In this situation, how yield benefits me ?

Comment: @syam: you can **reuse** the generator and do different things with the values. You could use `list(fibonacci(10))` to get a list. Or you could use `sum(fibonacci(10))` to get the sum. Or use `print(*fibonacci(10), sep='\n')` and print them all on separate lines. That's 3 different uses where the generator function *doesn't change at all*, and continues to be memory efficient.

Comment: If you _only_ want to print n terms of the Fibonacci sequence then there's no need to use a generator, you can just use a normal function that prints each Fibonacci number. But generally, the generator is more versatile. OTOH, if you need to calculate many individual Fibonacci numbers in random order, and it's likely that you want the same numbers many times, then there are better ways to do that, rather than producing the whole sequence up to n every time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By yielding the value, the *caller* of the function has access to the intermediate results, making this memory efficient.

For example, the following would give you all results up to `n` as well, but requires that you create a list first to hold those values:

```
def fibonacci(n):
    results = []
    curr = 1
    prev = 0
    counter = 0
    while counter < n:
        results.append(curr)
        prev, curr = curr, prev + curr
        counter += 1
    return results
```

If my code then asked for `fibonacci(10 ** 9)`, that would not only take a long time to produce, but would also require a *significant* amount of memory.

The generator option gives the caller access to the results immediately, which means they can use *just that one intermediate result* in another part of the program.)

This makes the generator function far more versatile and flexible. You could sum the fibonacci results, without having to rewrite the generator, for example:

```
sum_of_fibonacci_10 = sum(fibonacci(10))
```

This is still memory efficient, the summing takes place as the results are produced, at no point do all 10 results have to exist in memory. Just the current intermediate value, and the sum total up to now, are required.

If you wanted to just print the values instead, you can do so in a loop:

```
for next_value in fibonacci(10):
    print(next_value)
```

and the code is still just as efficient, and we still did not have to change the generator function.

So generators let you *maintain and share intermediate state*, saving you memory. This can be done with a class too, but a generator is much more readable. The following would do the same, but is not nearly as easy to follow:

```
class FibonacciGenerator:
    def __init__(self, n):
        self.n = n
        self.curr = 1
        self.prev = 0
        self.counter = 0

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        if self.counter >= self.n:
            raise StopIteration
        self.prev, self.curr = self.curr, self.prev + self.curr
        self.counter += 1
        return self.prev
```

Comment: I thought the question was about  `print` vs `yield` rather than `yield`ing vs `append`ing, but based on the voting on my answer, I might be wrong

Comment: @Chris_Rands: It's about what advantages `yield` has over alternatives *like* printing, or appending to a list. The OP in comments also asks about appending to a list.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Thanks. But in this, are you telling that if I didn't use generator in the example mentioned in question,  it will store all the fibonacci number  which it generated in its memory and in case of generator, it wont save all numbers?, Why it should save all numbers in memory in case of non-generator code, if I am not explicitly storing the produced values?

Comment: @syam: if you are not explicitly storing the values, then the caller can't have access to them either. You then reduced the usefulness and flexibility of the function.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Okey,  say user want to store all values. He is not using generator. He stored in to a list. say it consumed 5 MB memory. In other case if he use generator and  still he want to store the value. there also he used list(generator_object) OR just list.append() for each number generator produce. Still he uses 5 MB for storing the list correct? Only advantage I am seeing is he can get element one by one in generator. If he want to store the data, using generator may not give advantage over non generator method. is this correct?

Comment: @syam: yes, in both cases you'd use the same memory, you produced the same result. In that case the generator has a performance impact; just storing straight into a list is going to be faster.

Answer (score 1):

The advantage of a generator instead of a function is that it can keep its state.

If you had used a recursive function, calculating the 5th fibonacci number would be equivalent to calculating the 1st, then calculating the 1st and 2nd, then calculating the 1st, 2nd and 3rd, and so on until the 5th.

You can see how this is the problem for large numbers; there's a lot of resources being wasted.

With a generator, you calculate the 1st, and remember what it is, so that you don't have to calculate it again in order to find the second. Unlike a function that stops when it reaches its return, the generator can keep state. So it calculates the 1st number, and when requested, calculates the 2nd, then the 3rd, without wasting processing power because it doesn't need to recalculate the whole thing each time; it remembers its previous state.

With regards to print vs yield, obviously you can't use the printed result if you want to use the fibonacci numbers you calculated for something else; it's just output on the screen. If you'd like to generate a graph, for example, `print` wouldn't do, you'd have to pass values to your plotting function.

Answer (score 0):

Using a generator allows you to generate the 'tip' of the sequence **one at a time**, at your leisure. You can retrieve and print the result, but you don't need to.

A plain ol' loop in a function would run until the breaking condition was met - or forever - and without any special bells and whistles, would **block the execution** of your code until the loop terminated.

This means an unbounded loop would **only** stop once you killed the interpreter, and soon enough you'd *have* to kill it because it would start eating resources like crazy computing very high sums.

Yield **pauses between calls** and *returns* the value rather than just displaying it unlike print(). This means you can retrieve nth fibonacci number, do some other stuff for five minutes, then retrieve n+1th number.